# Android - Get traffic stats per ip source destination

Tags: android

I wanted to find bytes send/byte recvd per ip destination from my android phone.
I googled around, i found iptables way - https://code.google.com/p/iptableslog/

but it requires rooting the device. Is there any other way class traffic stats (doesnt provide per destination counters)

I am talking about the latest android version 
Any suggestions/workround  is welcome

Answer (score 0):

Here is the workaround i am using for getting stats -

Add a broadcast receiver

```
<receiver android:name=".core.CoreReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION" />
    <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And in class file -

```
/**
 * @author me
 */
public class CoreReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (Constants.phone == null) {
      // Receive [network] event
      Constants.phone=new PhoneListen(context);
      TelephonyManager telephony=(TelephonyManager) 
      context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
      telephony.listen(Constants.phone, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_DATA_CONNECTION_STATE);
    }

    WifiManager wifi=(WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    boolean b=wifi.isWifiEnabled();
    if (Constants.STATUS_WIFI != b) {
       // WiFi status changed...
    }
  }
}
```

Listen all the phone state -

```
public class PhoneListen extends PhoneStateListener {
  private Context context;    
  public PhoneListen(Context c) {
     context=c;
  }    
  @Override
  public void onDataConnectionStateChanged(int state) {
    switch(state) {
      case TelephonyManager.DATA_DISCONNECTED:// 3G
        //3G has been turned OFF
      break;
      case TelephonyManager.DATA_CONNECTING:// 3G
        //3G is connecting
      break;
      case TelephonyManager.DATA_CONNECTED:// 3G
        //3G has turned ON
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Then use trafficstat for getting the data -

```
long totalbyte = Trafficstats.getTotalRxBytes();
long mobilenetworkbyte = Trafficstats.getMobileRxBytes();
String total = Long.toString(totalbyte);
String mobile = Long.toString(mobilenetworkbyte);
String wifibyte = total - mobile + "kb";
```

Add this data in sqlite database when it is connected, and stop sending data when there is no connection.

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Hello Ashish, does this provide traffic stats per destination, when i say destination, I mean say I have 5 apps, and they are sending and recv data on Ip. I want to know which IPs they are connecting to and whats the byte send and recvd